# how to convert formula to if else from excel in php

Tags: excel

i just want to know what this formula means .need help.  please elaborate with if else statements.

```
 =(IF(D11<=49.69,8.2404,IF(D11<50,((50-D11)*100*0.2084)+1.78, IF(D11>50.04, 0, ((50.05-D11)*100*0.356)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the logic:

```
 If (D11<=49.69) Then
    8.2404
 Else
    If (D11<50) Then
        ((50-D11)*100*0.2084)+1.78
    Else
        If (D11>50.04) Then
            0
        Else
            ((50.05-D11)*100*0.356)
        End if
    End If
 End if
```

translated in php as:

```
if ($D11 <= 49.69) {
    $x = 8.2404;
 } elseif ($D11 < 50) {
    $x = ((50-$D11)*100*0.2084)+1.78;
 } elseif ($D11>50.04) {
    $x = 0;
 } else {
    $x = ((50.05-$D11)*100*0.356)
 }
```

Comment: i added the php version of it, don't forget to accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of the `IF` function in Excel is `=IF(condition,value1,value2)` where `condition` is something that evaluates to either `TRUE` or `FALSE`. `value1` and `value2` can be anything valid for insertion into an Excel cell: number, text or a formula. In the question, `value2` is a formula which just happens to be another `IF` function and which also happens to contain further `IF`'s in its arguments.

You can think of an `IF` in programming terms as

`If Condition Then Value1 Else Value2 End If'

The Help system in Excel is usually quite useful and a lot quicker than posting here and waiting for replies.